# Aggregate values for all combinations of factor levels including missing ones

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the minimum value of a dataframe based on multiple columns.  I'm able to do this successfully using the aggregate function below. However, the result does NOT contain combinations of factors where there is no data in the input data frame.

What I've got:

```
# all possibilities of fruits, cities, and vegetables:
fruits<-c('apple','banana','grape')
cities<-c('new york','chicago','los angeles')
vegetables<-c('cucumber','mushroom')

#my input (ie, a sample from a test:
inputdf<-data.frame(fruit=c('apple','apple','apple','banana','banana','banana','grape','grape','grape'),city=c('new york','new york','new york','new york','chicago','los angeles','chicago','chicago','chicago'),vegetable=c('cucumber','cucumber','mushroom','cucumber','mushroom','mushroom','cucumber','cucumber','cucumber'),value=c(5,3,4,6,5,7,2,7,4))

#my aggregation:
outdf<-aggregate(value ~ fruit + city + vegetable,inputdf,function(x) min(x))
```

The output I get is:

```
fruit   city        vegetable   value
grape   chicago     cucumber    2
apple   new york    cucumber    3
banana  new york    cucumber    6
banana  chicago     mushroom    5
banana  los angeles mushroom    7
apple   new york    mushroom    4
```

This is correct, however, I also want the rows that correspond to the combinations of columns that didnt exist at all in the input df:

```
fruit   city        vegetable   value
apple   new york    cucumber    3
apple   new york    mushroom    4
apple   chicago     cucumber    NA
apple   chicago     mushroom    NA
apple   los angeles cucumber    NA
apple   los angeles mushroom    NA
banana  new york    cucumber    6
banana  new york    mushroom    NA
banana  chicago     cucumber    NA
banana  chicago     mushroom    5
banana  los angeles cucumber    NA
banana  los angeles mushroom    7
grape   new york    cucumber    NA
grape   new york    mushroom    NA
grape   chicago     cucumber    2
grape   chicago     mushroom    NA
grape   los angeles cucumber    NA
grape   los angeles mushroom    NA
```

I'd like to be able to do this for any number of columns on which to combine.  is there a simple way to do that?  The reason I want that output is because I then need to transform the NAs to a specific value and average those values over the same subsets again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `expand.grid` to generate all combinations, then using `merge`:

```
outdf<-aggregate(value ~ fruit + city + vegetable,inputdf,function(x) min(x))
DF=expand.grid(fruits, cities, vegetables)
outdf=merge(outdf,DF,by.x=c('fruit','city','vegetable'),by.y=c('Var1','Var2','Var3'),all.y=T) 
> outdf
    fruit        city vegetable value
1   apple     chicago  cucumber    NA
2   apple     chicago  mushroom    NA
3   apple los angeles  cucumber    NA
4   apple los angeles  mushroom    NA
5   apple    new york  cucumber     3
6   apple    new york  mushroom     4
7  banana     chicago  cucumber    NA
8  banana     chicago  mushroom     5
9  banana los angeles  cucumber    NA
10 banana los angeles  mushroom     7
11 banana    new york  cucumber     6
12 banana    new york  mushroom    NA
13  grape     chicago  cucumber     2
14  grape     chicago  mushroom    NA
15  grape los angeles  cucumber    NA
16  grape los angeles  mushroom    NA
17  grape    new york  cucumber    NA
18  grape    new york  mushroom    NA
```